About c++ multithreaded code converted to WebAssembly view rendering problem in js call
var Module = {
        print: (function() {
          var element = document.getElementById('output');
          test_element=document.getElementById('test_element');
          // if (element) element.value = ''; // clear browser cache
          return (...args) => {
            var text = args.join(' ');
            // These replacements are necessary if you render to raw HTML
            //text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
            //text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
            //text = text.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
            //text = text.replace('\n', '<br>', 'g');
            console.log(text);
            if (element) {
              element.value += text + "\n";
              element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; // focus on bottom
            }
            if(test_element){
              test_element.value+=text;
            }
          };
        })(),

The above code is part of the main.html file that is automatically generated using WebAssembly. The c++ code in the source file is multi-threaded code with printf output in each thread. I want to know why when I run main.html, my update to element.value appears in the  interface only after the main function has executed and all the printf has been printed, but in the browser console, console.log, which I use in my code, will normally execute one output piece after another.
Here is the c++ code for the source file
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

const unsigned total = 1e9;
const unsigned tasks = 10;
void *callback(void *arg) {
    printf("arg value: %d\n", *(int *)arg);
    return NULL;
}
void heavy_task() {
    unsigned cnt = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        cnt ++;
    }
}
void* divided_task(void *arg) {
    unsigned cnt = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < total/tasks; i++) {
        cnt++;
    }
    sleep(1);
    printf("task %d is finished\n", *(int*)(arg));
    return NULL;
}
int main() {
    clock_t start = clock();
    heavy_task();
    clock_t end = clock();
    printf("time for task1 is %ld\n", (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    start = clock();
    pthread_t tid;
    int arr[tasks] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, divided_task, &arr[i]);
        printf("thread_id is %d\n", (int)tid);
    }
    end = clock();
    sleep(5);
    printf("time for task2 is %ld\n", (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}


How can I make my changes to element.value appear in real time on the  tag
